# Python Clear() method to delete a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using clear to delete a dictionary. So imagine I want to delete the first dictionary which is called newDict.

```
myList = [
    {
        'foo':12,
        'bar':14
    },
    {
        'moo':52,
        'car':641
    },
    {
        'doo':6,
        'tar':84
    }
]

newDict.clear()

myList = [
    {
        
    },
    {
        'moo':52,
        'car':641
    },
    {
        'doo':6,
        'tar':84
    }
]
```

But I want to delete also the **{}** in the output.

Comment: You can't, unless you implement a custom `dict`.

Comment: What do doy mean by writing?

Comment: What should it print instead? An empty string, None, something else?

Comment: The `{}` indicates an empty dict. "Clearing" a dict would result in an empty dict, so `{}` seems correct.

Comment: @Max edited my comment to clarify.

Comment: `.clear()` empties the dict, if you want to delete it use `del`. Otherwise please specify your expected output.

Comment: Updated the question. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Del is not working in this case @Andreas

Comment: The edit doesn't make it better. Please provide a [mre]. Currently it has no output at all.

Comment: If you don't like the default output of Python, write a method that outputs exactly as you wish. That's basically it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully delete the first dictionary in the list use del by index:

```
del myList[0]

print(myList)
# Out[45]: [{'moo': 52, 'car': 641}, {'doo': 6, 'tar': 84}]
```

If you only want to `.clear()` it, use clear by index instead:

```
myList[0].clear()

print(myList)
#[{}, {'moo': 52, 'car': 641}, {'doo': 6, 'tar': 84}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `clear()` method cleans out all the key-value pairs, leaving an empty dict. That refers to the dict **repr** method. If you want to clean the object completely, just `del` it: `del text`. The GC then will destroy the object in the memory. But be careful: after deleting variable is destroyed completely, so you'll get `NameError: name 'text' is not defined` when `print('text =', text)` occurs.

Another approach here is to subclass `dict` class, but implement your own `__repr__()` method:

```py
class CustomDict(dict):

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        if len(self):
            return super().__repr__()
        else:
            return ''


text = CustomDict(a='geeks', b='for')
text.clear()

print('text =', text)
```